# How can I best run a daily script that updates my Django App with content from external URLs in Digital Ocean App Platform?

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I have a Django Web App set up on the Digital Ocean App Platform. I want to update my Django App daily with content from external URLs. Unfortunately, cron jobs are not available in the App Platform.

Specifically, I want to fetch images from external URLs, attempt to download the images, and update it in my Django App if the download was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider configuring celery and using celery beat for django, there you have many options configuring scheduled tasks without the need of a cronjob.

Documentation [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20scheduler%20is%20the,manage%20periodic%20tasks%20at%20runtime.)

Daemonize Celery [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html)

Example of how you would use celery beat:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')

    # Calls test('world') every 30 seconds
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, test.s('world'), expires=10)

    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        test.s('Happy Mondays!'),
    )

@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    z = x + y
    print(z)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in terms of how I would set that up in practice on the App Platform?

Comment: How you would setup celery?

Comment: More so how to use Celery in the context of the Digital Ocean App Platform. In case of using your code sample above, where would I set it up in the Digital Ocean?

Comment: You'll need install and daemonize RabbitMQ or Redis. Once they're configured, then you can daemonize celery.